# Is there any Information extraction to find subject and verb/relation doubles in sentence just like ClausIE, Reverb, etc?

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp, information-extraction

I have used ClausIE and it returns the Subject, verb and Object triples from a sentence. But these won't work when the text is short text and not even a complete sentence. I just want a library or otherwise which can return just the subject verb pairs from short text/phrase.

An example short text is "Proposal 32 accepted". It should have some dependency or maybe rules used to identify that the term "Proposal" is the subject and the term "accepted" is verb/relation.

I have tried Stanford online parser for the above text but it doesn't return anything maybe because there is no object in the text.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, you got a Subject ("Proposal 32") and a Verb ("accepted"). Because you don't have an Object, there's no triple.

But, what you could do, is to try to identify the Subject and the Verb, by using Tokenization, using Stanford online

For example:
- The sentence is probably "declarative" if Stanford uses the "S" tag.
- if the sentence is declarative, then:
-  the Subject is usually the Noun group that is in front of the main Verb group. In Stanford online that's the first NP in front of the first VP.

Now: if you: 
- Add "is" in front of the main verb you get: "Proposal 32 is accepted".
- Which is: "Proposal 32 = accepted", which is a logical comparison that any programming language understands

The problem of course is, you don't always get these simple short sentences. There are probably some packages out there that can deal with this out-of-the-box. But not that I know of.

What you can do: make some rules of your own, based on English grammar. It would only understand sentences for the rules that you make. But maybe that's all you need. If you only have to deal with these very short combinations, a few well designed rules can do the job